# GeoFire Firebase Swift in realtime

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

Please how can make it in real time ?
like adding addSnapshotListener.
This code is only work when it called, I wanna if you change in FireBase, the reflect will be on the frontend.

reference >>> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries

```
// Find cities within 50km of London
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5074, longitude: 0.1278)
let radiusInM: Double = 50 * 1000

// Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
// a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
// depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
let queryBounds = GFUtils.queryBounds(forLocation: center,
                                      withRadius: radiusInM)
let queries = queryBounds.map { bound -> Query in
    return db.collection("cities")
        .order(by: "geohash")
        .start(at: [bound.startValue])
        .end(at: [bound.endValue])
}

var matchingDocs = [QueryDocumentSnapshot]()
// Collect all the query results together into a single list
func getDocumentsCompletion(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) -> () {
    guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
        print("Unable to fetch snapshot data. \(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    for document in documents {
        let lat = document.data()["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
        let lng = document.data()["lng"] as? Double ?? 0
        let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        let centerPoint = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)

        // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash accuracy, but
        // most will match
        let distance = GFUtils.distance(from: centerPoint, to: coordinates)
        if distance <= radiusInM {
            matchingDocs.append(document)
        }
    }
}

// After all callbacks have executed, matchingDocs contains the result. Note that this
// sample does not demonstrate how to wait on all callbacks to complete.
for query in queries {
    query.getDocuments(completion: getDocumentsCompletion)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), you can use `.addSnapshotListener` instead of `getDocuments`. Since this is not directly related to the geoquery, the solution documents the simpler approach - but the code for geoquerying would work exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your replay,
Could you please write the code for me?

Comment: I'm still new in firebase

Comment: I followed your answer about "Declared closure result 'ListenerRegistration' is incompatible with contextual type 'Query'
Replace 'Query' with 'Query' :D"

Comment: Please could you migrate the code?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You're trying to significantly expand the use-case that is covered in the docs, and while I am excited to see you try take on that challenge, I can't write that code for you (otherwise it'd be in the docs). --- Search for any error message you get, as likely they've shown up before. If after really trying it yourself you're unable to get it to work, edit your question with an update that shows [what you tried based on my answer and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thanks for your reply,
I'm in loop with this since 3 days with no success.
I apologize, the answer wasn't clear enough for me to understand.
I tried different ways with no success
My main goal is to build real time with geo services and I did almost everything and I'm unable to continue.

Comment: I understood the goal already: you want to take the [documented non-realtime geoquery solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#swift) and make that work with data that updates in real time. I included the high-level change that you'll need to make in my answer. But writing the code for turning a documented complex solution into an even more complex solution that fits your use-case is quite a bit beyond what we can reasonably do here on Stack Overflow. You'll have to do that yourself, or find somebody who's willing to do it for you (which is off-topic here).

Comment: If you have a concrete question about how the code from the documented solution works, we might be able to help. Or if you took the guidance I gave and tried to implement, we might also be able to help if you show where you got stuck. But what you're asking so far is just too broad for this site.